# Templates, typeinfo and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, typeinfo

I'm trying to write a template function to help with accessing classes stored in a tree structure (a Qt model as it happens, but that isn't important). Every item in the tree is derived from the same class, but there are two branches of derived class, each with their own types. 
I'll use an analogy, say I have a base class Vehicle, and two main subclasses LandVehicle and SeaVehicle. LandVehicles have subclasses with a LandVehicle type() function returning a class specific type enum, land_vehicle_type_e, say "car", "truck", "skateboard", as do SeaVehicles with sea_vehicle_type_e: "boat", "jetski", etc. I.e a Truck is a subclass of LandVehicle which is a subclass of Vehicle.

I need a function to pull every "car" from the tree, or every "SeaVehicle". I am trying to do this with template functions, avoiding the type enums, instead using the typeinfo() function.

My plan of attack has been to create a template function as follows:

```
template class< T>
QList<QStandardItem*> MyModel::vehicles(T *vehicletype)
{
   <iterating over tree items which have a function to return stored data>
   {

     T * data = dynamic_cast<T*> item->vehicle();
     if(typeinfo(data) == typeinfo(vehicletype)
     {
       <add to list of return values>
     }
   }
}
```

I'm now doubtful this will work as I intend it to. For instance, can I use a function like this:

```
QList<QStandardItem*> vehicles<Vehicle>(Vehicle *myVehicle){}
```

And pass it a subclass of Vehicle such as Truck, and expect it to return a list of Trucks (because the typeinfo() of the Vehicle passed in will be equivalent to "Truck"?) Or since my template type is Vehicle, will it return a list of every Vehicle, since the typeinfo of Vehicle will be equivalent to "Vehicle"?

It seems to me that if the templates are expanded using Vehicle then the latter would be true.
If this is the case, can you suggest a better way to handle this situation without relying on switch statements? I am trying to rework a current system which in the above analogy only has to deal with LandVehicles, and uses the type() function to decide what to return. I would like a way to handle arbitrary subclasses of Vehicle() without needing to code for each new type.

To clarify the question: (sorry @Barry!), I would like a single function that I can pass any subclass of Vehicle, which will return all other items in the tree of that same subclass type. I am trying to avoid having to code separately for each derived type.

Comment: To be more concise: You have two `Vehicle*` pointers and you want to test if they point to objects of the same dynamic type?

Comment: I have a tree of a number of pointers to derived classes. I want to extract all the items of the same type as one I pass in dynamically.

Comment: Is the type required from the function call known at compile-time?

Comment: no, it needs to be dynamic. It seems that by doing this with templates I would still end up with a set of functions for each type, so I think my answer below is more appropriate (no templates, use typeinfo for comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have answered my own question. Since all the items in the tree are of the same base class, I don't really need a template function at all. 
I can compare the typeinfo() of the input class with that of each item in the tree